# Can I install MS Access 2019 on a subscribed Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, ms-access

Sorry if this question is too simple.
I am provided with the license to MS Access (probably 2019) by my school. I need to use the software. However, I have a Mac Book and cannot install the software there. Hence is it possible and allowable to subscribe to Azure and install the software on the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, you can treat vms like a physical machine, but virtual machines are not cheap. Are you set up for student Azure credit.

Comment: Use Oracle Virtual Box, install Windows 10 and then you can install Access there. No need for an Azure Subscription just for this :).

Comment: @GauravMantri But is buying Windows 10 even more expensive than subscribing to Azure (if only a virtual machine is needed)? I only need to use it for 2 months.

Comment: You can [get student credit of $100/month](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-students-faq/). As long as you shut down the vm when you are not using it you should stay within that limit.

Comment: You can run Windows 10 in trial mode :).

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks, then I have to check whether my school has provided us with this offer.

Comment: Actually, anyone can sign up for an Azure trial. You can get $200 credit for the first month. If you only need it for two months then being diligent about shutting the vm down will keep your costs very low.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks a lot! By shutting down the vm, are all installed software and data still in the vm? If it's the case, does it mean I always log in to the same remote machine every time I connect?

Comment: You won't lose anything by shutting down. You will need to start the vm and then remote into it. It's a bit tedious because it takes a few minutes but it's better than paying full time. You can automate it too with powershell or az cli - `az vm start -g <your resource group> -n <the vm name>`